# RegEx for numbers with exactly 5 digits and only one allowed leading zero

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex for a number that must have exactly 5 digits with one allowed leading zero, but not more than one.

What is valid: 12345, 01234, 01015, 01111, 10000
What is NOT valid: 1234, 123456, 00123, 00001, 00012

This is what I had before (when no leading zeroes are allowed):

```
/^(?!0)\d{5}$/
```

and this is how I tried to "expand" the expression:

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,5})$
```

but now all numbers with less than 5 digits are valid, and the most important change (one allowed leading zero) is not working.

Where did I mess up in the second expression? Or am I just missing one condition in my original expression?

Comment: Looks like you do not want to allow two or more zeros at the start: `/^(?!00)\d{5}$/` - https://regex101.com/r/zTy1FW/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! Didn't think about "?!00" to not allow multiple leading zeroes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily solve the problem with a negative lookahead if you re-phrase the problem: you want to match any five-digit string that does not start with two (or more) zeros:

```
^(?!00)\d{5}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zTy1FW/1).

Also, the regex can be re-written without a lookahead (just in case you need to use the pattern with a regex engine that does not support PCRE-like features):

```
^(0[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4})$
```

If `\d` is supported:

```
^(0[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4})$
```

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt to *"expand" the expression* can be fixed as following.

```
^(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)\d{3}$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3kQc3T/1)

I used a [`(?:` non capturing group `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) for [alternating](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) the options.

Answer (score 1):

You could start the match with 2 digits, then assert that there are no 2 zeroes to the left and then match the last 3 digits:

```
^\d\d(?<!00)\d{3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/te9LA7/2)